# Tokens not working in entity form

Tags: 7, forms, entities, tokens

I put together a simple entity form and am trying to enter a few default token values for fields on the form.
But when I choose something like [site:current-user:mail] from the list of available tokens, it displays literally as typed.
Which is to say that, in the input box where the user's email is supposed to have been inserted, I'm seeing the text - "[site:current-user:mail]" instead in that field, which is a bit strange, since tokens seem to be working everywhere else on the site.

I'm using the latest stable version of drupal 7 and the entityform module.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [**Field default token**](https://drupal.org/project/field_default_token) module and then edit the entityforms type and save again with the desired tokens selected, and it should work.